# My function doesn't send data to my database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I don't know why this function is not sending the data, I think I already passed all the needed stuff from my backend. What do I lack in my code?

This is my StreetNavigation.js

```
function recordTravel(){

    fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/users/travels`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        body: JSON.stringify({

        })
    })
    }
```

This is my route

```
router.post('/travels', auth.verify, (req, res) => {
    const params = {
        userId: auth.decode(req.headers.authorization).id,
        travel: {
            origin: {
                longitude: req.body.originLong,
                latitude: req.body.originLat
            },
            destination: {
                longitude: req.body.destinationLong,
                latitude: req.body.destinationLat
            },
            distance: req.body.distance,
            duration: req.body.duration
        }
    }
    UserController.addTravel(params).then(result => res.send(result))
})
```

It's supposed to pick up the data, then redirect to my history.js for some record viewing

Comment: `body` is missing in fetch call

Comment: @NileshPatel I've already added it, still not sending anything

Comment: did you console log to see what you getting on `req.body`

Comment: Try adding console.log() functions in relevant places to see if you can figure out what's going on. Is the `recordTravel` function even being executed?  If so, what data is being sent to the server? Look in your browser's dev tools (network tab) and analyze the XHR request. If everything looks right on the client side, add console.log's on the server side to see what is being executed.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the tip, I'll try the console.log on the server side